# Error in OneModelica using Dymola compiler

Tags: modelica, dymola

I keep getting the error "Errors or failure to expand a concealed equation" while trying to run a model on OneModelica using Dymola compiler. Has anyone faced such an error before?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, please take this opportunity to learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This error usually occurs when a there is an error in an encrypted part of a library. For any useful help consider extending the question as suggested in the comment from Jescanellas

Comment: Where could I find OneModelica? I can't find its website.